# when is fileUploadListener invoked?

Tags: jsf-2, actionlistener

Can anybody tell me when is the fileUploadListener invoked and also in which phase.I am using PrimeFaces.

Comment: Why are you asking such a trivial question which you could answer yourself by just debugging the code and/or printing/logging the current phase ID? What exactly is the problem you're actually trying to solve? Ask a question about exactly that problem instead.

Comment: Actually i am new to JSF. How can I print the current phase ID?

Answer (score 0):

fileUploadListener is executed before phase APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2 (I'm using PF 3.5)

You can checkout current phase implementing a lifecycle listener, this way:

```
package mypackage;

import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;

public class LifeCycleListener implements PhaseListener {

public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
}

public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("START PHASE " + event.getPhaseId());
}

public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("END PHASE " + event.getPhaseId());
}

}
```

Then, add your new Listener to faces-config.xml:

```
<lifecycle>
<phase-listener>mypackage.LifeCycleListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

Don't forget to add your logs for primefaces messages!

Cheers!